# Cannot install Xubuntu 16.04 on Acer Aspire 5315 with Intel Celeron 530 (Laptop)

Tags: xubuntu

I hope you can be of some help to me!
So I downloaded Xubuntu 16.04 ISO and burnt it using my MBA 2012 under OS X El Capitan.
Then I'd like to install Xubuntu on one of my older laptops, which is an Acer Aspire 5315 whose configuration is as follows : 2GB DDR2 RAM, 120GB SATA2 HDD, Intel Celeron M 530, 1280x800 display (I know, it really is an old and very low performance laptop which is why I chose Xubuntu over Ubuntu or any of its derivatives with fancier graphics). I then booted to the Xubuntu DVD and could go up to the language selection and 'accessibility' menu of the DVD. However, afterwards (I tried multiple times), I then get either an 'emergency shutdown' or a kernel panic (according to the terminal-like text I have on the screen). I also tried enabling acpi=off as I had trouble installing Lubuntu on a laptop with a Celeron M from 2006 and it solved the problem (which seemed different though as it clearly indicated a sleep-wake issue) on this laptop.
Question is: do you have any how I could successfully install Xubuntu 16.04 on this machine? Once, I know this an old laptop, it ram Windows 10 honorably and I'd love to be able to install Xubuntu on this machine despite its age.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have to use **forcepae**! I remember having to do that with the other Celeron M (although it was around 1.5 years older). I will try it out as soon as possible!